# How can SOAP be used with Spring Reactor's WebClient?

Tags: spring, soap, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I've managed to build an SSL connection to the sandbox server and to send the object as a serialised XML object by applying the content type MediaType.APPLICATION_XML. However, this is not enough as the target service only supports SOAP and expects the message properly wrapped in an envelope.

```
        final var webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(fmdConfiguration.getSinglePackUrl())
                .clientConnector(connector)
                .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
                .filter(logResponseStatus())
                .filter(logRequest())
                .build();

        return webClient
                .method(GET)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(SinglePackPingResponse.class);
```

This is the response from the service:

```
Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"
```

Unfortunately the the WebClient doesn't support the media type application/soap+xml. When I try to use it, then the WebClient throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=eu.nmvs.SinglePackPingRequest
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:300)
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? "Why isn't my code working" type questions are very hard to answer with snippets like the above.

Comment: @Andras, did you manage to get this working?

Comment: @AmosKosgei No, I applied the approach described in https://blog.godatadriven.com/jaxws-reactive-client

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
private void acceptedCodecs(ClientCodecConfigurer clientCodecConfigurer) {
    clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().encoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_XML));
    clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().decoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_XML));
}
```

and:

```
  webClient = webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl(baseUrL)
                .filter(logRequest())
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(this::acceptedCodecs).build()).build();
```